What's best practice when grouting in tight spaces like shower niches?
About to start grouting my shower, and wondering how I should go about a few things.
My niche corners have very little spacing where the metal corners join and the corners and the tile.  Some literally are touching one another. See pictures.

What is used on the niche areas in the picture I marked with red, green, and blue – silicone or grout? I’m trying to get a consensus.  The backing is all entirely waterproofed, so does it make a difference?  I am using sanded grout, so it won’t fit into super tiny spaces.  I also have silicone/caulk that matches the grout color, so I can use either.

I can Dremel the corners between the metal joints (marked green) to make for a wider joint for the grout (if grout is used there) – should I?



Many thanks in advance.

Personally, I'd use caulk at all of those arrows, given that they're all effectively changes of plane...

You won't get a consensus. Some just use the grout, since it's already available and isn't too difficult. Some prefer caulk for ease of application, better hold, and crack resistance. You decide.
I would not grind out the channels. You're likely to create wavy or chipped edges which will not improve appearance.
If you're grouting, just use a tool to press it in and create a small cove. A rubber trowel can work (they sometimes have one or two rounded corners), or a sponge, or your fingers.
If you're caulking, cut the nozzle to a small tip at an angle. Press the caulk into the void for best hold. If needed, tool it out to cove it, but avoid widening the bead by cleaning the tool or finger often.
In either case, avoid leaving a large cove at the intersection of the corners. That tends to look unprofessional. The cove should be consistent all the way to the actual intersecting face.
